# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void ListView.setAdapter(ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show an image and text each list view item. I read a few tutorial but I still could not.

I'm getting this error when I try to open TagsActivity:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

In this line:

```
this.tagList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**TagsActivity.java**

```
public class TagsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public ListView tagList;
final List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tags.add(new Tag("Black & White"));
    tags.add(new Tag("Geometric"));

    this.tagList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_tags);
    LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, this.tags);
    this.tagList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**Tag.java**

```
public class Tag {
private String title;

public Tag(String title) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

**JazyAdapter.java**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Tag> tags;

public LazyAdapter(Activity activity, List<Tag> tags) {
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.tags = tags;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.tags.size();
}

@Override
public Tag getItem(int position) {
    return this.tags.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    Tag tag = this.tags.get(position);

    textView.setText(tag.getTitle());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

    return row;
}
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp"
android:background="@drawable/border_bottom">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumb"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumb"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="Black &amp; White"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_tags.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_tags"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because of "View row" is null. Just replace that in your **LazyLoader.java**

```
View row;
row = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
```

With:

```
View row = convertView;
if (row == null) {
    row = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}
```

Comment: Instead of only posting a class you might want to clarify why this would solve the issue as asked in the question. That way the poster can learn from it, as well as future users.

Comment: Because my English is very bad =(

Answer (score 0):

`this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` should be `this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_tags);`

Comment: Thanks, I guess that was a mistake, but I still get same error. :(